# Kotlin - how to know if a String is present in a Constant object?

Tags: android, kotlin, casting

I'm working on an Android application where I've created an `object` in Constants file to store some Status values. In one of my classes, I've got a variable of type `Status`. I need to set the value of status from some data I get from backend. However, the data is in `String` form. Is there any way I can check whether the data string is in the `Status` object and potentially cast this string to `Status`?

NOTE: There can be many custom types like `Status`, so I want to avoid enums as much as possible given their performance impacts.

Consider the following scenario

```
// Constants.kt
object Constants {
    ...
    object Status {
        const val OKAY = "okay"
        const val DONE = "done"
        const val PENDING = "pending"
    }
    ...
}


// SomeClass.kt
class SomeClass {
    private var status: Status? = null

    setStatus(status: Status) {
        this.status = status
    }
}

// SomeOtherClass.kt
fun updateStatus() {
    val someClass = SomeClass()
    val status: String = getSomeStringFromServer()
    // add some check to confirm whether status is actually one of Constants.Status
    someClass.setStatus(status) // It wouldn't work because type String and Status are incompatible
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what happens if the String from you backend is matched to on of `Status` class variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only a number of finite reasoned states then you can easily use a `enum` :

```
enum class Status(val value : String) {
    OKAY("okay"),
    DONE("done"),
    PENDING("pending")
}
```

Then in order to convert the server string into a `Status` :

```
val valueFromServer = "okay"
val status : Status? = enumValues<Status>().firstOrNull { it.value == valueFromServer }
```

This works for known types and you can easily handle unknown types when the `Status` is null.

Also for convenience use you can create an extension function :

```
 private fun String.toStatus() : Status? = enumValues<Status>().firstOrNull { it.value == this }
```

Usage :

```
"okay".toStatus()
```

Comment: But isn't using enums bad in terms of performance/memory especially since I'll be having a large number of such custom types?

Comment: "I'll be having a large number of such custom types" - that's not mentioned in your question - this just talks about `Status`. For your example in the question an enum is more declarative and explicit for constrained finite type as apposed to random string constants - which are very generic considering they are just strings.  Enums don't work for unknown types, this is where you'd use collections, or other ways to parse values, if parsing or adapting is required.

Comment: I've updated my question statement to add more clarity. Thanks!